# is there a way to get multiple value for checkbox without using "[]"

Tags: html, for-loop, checkbox, limit, jscript

I wrote a code that needs to select multiple checkboxes, yet, it has a limiter upon selection but in my limit function it needs either `id` or `name` to be in the same order as to the function, and on my check box i have use the id for the label

see my code below:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="15" name="List4">
<label for="15" style="margin-top: 10px;">Baked Fish w/ Mushroom               Sauce</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="16" name="List4">
<label for="16" style="margin-top: 10px;">Poached Fish in Ginger Soy Sauce</label>                                                      
<input type="checkbox" id="17" name="List4">
<label for="17" style="margin-top: 10px;">Beer Battered Fish with Ranch</label>
```

The javascript is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
checkboxlimit(document.forms.form1.List4, 2)
</script>
```

on the header is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkboxlimit(checkgroup, limit){
var checkgroup=checkgroup
var limit=limit
for (var i=0; i<checkgroup.length; i++){
    checkgroup[i].onclick=function(){
    var checkedcount=0
    for (var i=0; i<checkgroup.length; i++)
        checkedcount+=(checkgroup[i].checked)? 1 : 0
    if (checkedcount>limit){
        alert("You can only select a maximum of "+limit+" checkboxes")
        this.checked=false
        }
    }
}
}
</script>
```

i have read if you need to select multiple data it need to name as an array

```
name[]
```

Comment: And... your problem is?

Comment: i like to get the value of those selected checkboxes without using the name="data[]" array functioning, if there is other way to avoid using that and still get the list of data out of the checkboxes

Comment: The `data[]` array notation is not for JavaScript, it's for (mainly) PHP to treat the incoming value as an actual array, and not as a string. JavaScript can handle names without [] as well.

Comment: It's enough when your checkboxes have the same name, "[]" is not necessary javascript-side

Comment: i wanted to get the value of the each selected textbox using PHP without using data[ ], if there is anyposible way to get multiple data without it.